# Как пропарсить названия значение определённого атрибута в каждом теге в div'e через JSoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Мне надо пропарсить кусок html, который я привёл ниже. В нём я пометил текст, который нужно пропарсить, он всегда находится в атрибуте alt. Так же, мне надо пропарсить ссылку (я её пометил как url.com) рядом с ним, и дату.
Пытался сначала пропарсить текст из атрибута alt вот таким куском кода:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.president.gov.ua/ua").get();
String title = doc.select("[alt]").attr("alt");
```

Но оно не работает. Строка title пустая.
Вот сам кусок html'я:

```
div class="main_slider">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="flexslider flexslider_main">
   <ul class="slides">
    <li>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 slide_col"><a href="url.com"> <img src="image" width="625" height="405" alt="ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ!"> <span class="round_btn video_icon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></span> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 slide_col">
       <div class="main_slider_caption">
        <div class="topic">
         <span>!</span>головне
        </div>
        <h2><a href="url.com">ЗАГОЛОВОК</a></h2>
        <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> дата </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></li>
    <li>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 slide_col"><a href="url.com"> <img src="image" width="625" height="405" alt="ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ"> <span class="round_btn video_icon"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></span> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 slide_col">
       <div class="main_slider_caption">
        <div class="topic">
         <span>!</span>головне
        </div>
        <h2><a href="url.com">Заголовок</a></h2>
        <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> дата </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></li>
    <li>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 slide_col"><a href="url.com"> <img src="image" width="625" height="405" alt="ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ"> <span class="round_btn video_icon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></span> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 slide_col">
       <div class="main_slider_caption">
        <div class="topic">
         <span>!</span>головне
        </div>
        <h2><a href="url.com">Заголовок</a></h2>
        <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> дата </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></li>
    <li>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 slide_col"><a href="url.com"> <img src="image" width="625" height="405" alt="ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 slide_col">
       <div class="main_slider_caption">
        <div class="topic">
         <span>!</span>головне
        </div>
        <h2><a href="url.com">Заголовок</a></h2>
        <p class="date">дата</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></li>
    <li>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7 slide_col"><a href="url.com"> <img src="image" width="625" height="405" alt="ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 slide_col">
       <div class="main_slider_caption">
        <div class="topic">
         <span>!</span>головне
        </div>
        <h2><a href="url.com">Заголовок</a></h2>
        <p class="date">дата</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Есть ли какой-то грамотный способ сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```java
doc.select("img").eachAttr("alt")
```

На выходе получим список из строк:

```
["ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ!", "ТЕКСТ КОТОРЫЙ НУЖНО СПАРСИТЬ", ...]
```

И, аналогично:

```java
doc.select("a").eachAttr("href")
```

На выходе:

```
["url.com", "url.com", "url.com", ...]
```